# getting null values when parsing json column in .csv file using from_json (using spark with scala ver 2.4)

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, parsing

H/a, i am getting null values when using from_json , can you help me figure out the missing piece here.
~ input is the .csv file with json e.g.

```
id,request
1,{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}
2,{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}
```

~my code (scala/spark)

```
val input_df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("escape","\"").csv(json_file_input)
 val json_schema_abc = StructType(Array(
      StructField("Zipcode",IntegerType,true),
      StructField("ZipCodeType",StringType,true),
      StructField("City",StringType,true),
      StructField("State",StringType,true))
    )
  val output_df =   input_df.select($"id",from_json(col("request"),json_schema_abc).as("json_request"))
                    .select("id","json_request.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is because the commas in your json column are being used as delimiters. If you have a look at the contents of you input_df:

```scala
val input_df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("escape","\"").csv(json_file_input)

input_df.show(false)
+---+--------------+
|id |request       |
+---+--------------+
|1  |{"Zipcode":704|
|2  |{"Zipcode":704|
+---+--------------+
```

You see that the `request` column is not complete: it was chopped off at the first comma in the `request` column.

The rest of your code is correct, you can test it like this:

```scala
val input_df = Seq(
  (1, """{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"""),
  (2, """{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State":"PR"}""")
).toDF("id","request")

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType}

val json_schema_abc = StructType(Array(
  StructField("Zipcode",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("ZipCodeType",StringType,true),
  StructField("City",StringType,true),
  StructField("State",StringType,true))
)

val output_df = input_df
  .select($"id",from_json(col("request"),json_schema_abc).as("json_request"))
  .select("id","json_request.*")

output_df.show(false)
+---+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+
|id |Zipcode|ZipCodeType|City               |State|
+---+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+
|1  |704    |STANDARD   |PARC PARQUE        |PR   |
|2  |704    |STANDARD   |PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|PR   |
+---+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+
```

I would suggest changing your CSV file's delimiter (for example `;` if that does not appear in your data), that way the commas won't be bothering you.